Excel VBA; How to use Target.Offset from a range so only the cell offset from the last cell in the range is populated?
I am using the following code to populate a cell with the current date and time when any cell in a range is modified. I want the cell in column O to populate with the date when I modify any cell from A through K.
It currently does populate the cell in column O but it also overwrites the cell offset 4 from the cell that was modified. How do I have it only populate O? (Ex. I modify E, it populates I and O)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:K")) Is Nothing Then
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            
            Target.Offset(0, 4) = ""
            
        Else
            
            Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            
        End If
        
    End If
End Sub

I tried modifying the range with reference but that didn't change anything. I attempted to make multiple statements for each column, but I didn't get the else/if statements to work properly.

Instead of using Offset, you could use something like
Cells(Target.Row, 15) = Now

or
Cells(Target.Row, "O") = Now

However, being in an event routine, consider

You might have modified more than cell at once (eg using cut&paste), so you should loop over all cells in Target
When you modify data in the change event routine, that will recursively trigger another change event. Best practice is to disable events to prevent this.

Also, if you want to have a date in Excel, don't write a formatted string into a cell, write the date itself into the cell and set the format of the cell (so that Excel don't have to guess if this is a date or not)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo change_exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(cell, Range("A:K")) Is Nothing Then
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                Cells(cell.Row, "O").Clear
            Else
                Cells(cell.Row, "O") = Now
            End If
        End If
    Next
change_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Use the row value of Target instead of offsetting the cell.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:K")) Is Nothing Then

    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
             Cells(Target.Row, 15).Value = ""
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row, 15).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub

